# Mavericks InstallESD.dmg MD5 checksum

Tags: macos, install

I've just downloaded OS X Mavericks on a Mac.

I'm trying to convert the file:

```
/Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app\Contents\SharedSupport\InstallESD.dmg
```

contained inside the download to a .cdr (AKA .iso AKA ISO 9660) file.

I've tried a couple of conversion programs but both of them
report that the file is corrupt.

Hence, I would like someone to post the MD5 checksum so that I may check the
file's integrity with the md5 command from the Mac shell?

That is the only way to determine whether this file is intact or not
and if someone could post the MD5 sum I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For OS X Mavericks 10.9.0 (build 13A603):

- MD5: f222952400db8535c03697c3293e168e
- SHA1: e804dea01e38f8cd28d6c1b1697487e50898dbe7

Comment: I would caution people. There are several builds of Mavericks and Apple doesn't guarantee that different hardware won't download a different InstallESD.dmg based on what build is required for a certain point release and hardware that's available.

Comment: Isn't there an official disk image with its `md5` and `sha1` checksums on the Apple web server?

Comment: @danielAzuelos what's served by Apple is not a disk image; it's more than the .dmg alone.

Comment: Yes, OS X Mavericks, like other versions of OS X, is only available from the App Store. However InstallESD.dmg is the bulk of the download. The whole OS is downloaded to /Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Mavericks.app . As of today 17 October 2013 this file corresponded to the posted MD5 checksum on my system. Thanks.